# T-SQL query, select IF same IP is used by more than one user within a fixed timespan

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to create a script checking IF the same source IP are used by more than one Login within a short time period, for example if someone are in possession of more than his/her own Login and poking around on others data.

This is the time frame I working with now and having data to test against.

```
SELECT UserIP, UserName 
FROM MySQLTableWithActivitiyRecords 
WHERE Event = 0 
  AND FORMAT(ActivityDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') = '2024-01-27 15'
```

I have this in the table (within the same hour)

```
1   123.123.123.1    John.smith@domain.com
2   123.123.123.1    Ian.Wally@domain.com
3   123.123.123.1    Eve.Lotion@domain.com
4   123.123.123.1    Tom.hardware@domain.com
5   190.190.190.2    Meg.Meghan@domain.com
```

I find it pretty suspicious that 4 users are signing in within 60 minutes using the same source IP and would like to get a heads-up about it (actually the sign-in was done within 5 mins).

I know I cannot just group by since that will not get duplicate IP with unique names.

I assume I need a CTE to do the magic comparison but I can't figure out how to write it.

I would like to get reply like:

```
1 123.123.123.1     4
```

Or even better is getting the 4 records with the names stated but only if the IP is the same.

If none of the IP is used twice by minimum two user names, then no records comes out.

So, if the same user signing twice in 5 minutes with the same IP, that's fine and should not be listed.

Thanks

Kjell

This is getting the 4 repeated IP, but will get same result even if used by same Login

```
SELECT [UserIP], COUNT([UserName]) 
FROM MySQLTableWithActivitiyRecords 
WHERE Event = 0 
  AND FORMAT(ActivityDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') = '2024-01-27 15'  
GROUP BY [UserIP] 
HAVING COUNT([UserName]) > 1 
ORDER BY [UserIP]
```

Comment: Try adding this to your HAVING clause: MIN ([UserName])<> MAX ([UserName])

Comment: Use ``COUNT(DISTINCT [UserName])``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example.
With test data:

```
create table MySQLTableWithActivityRecords (id int,Event int,UserIP varchar(15)
     ,UserName varchar(50) ,ActivityDate datetime);
insert  into MySQLTableWithActivityRecords values
 (1,0,'123.123.123.1','John.smith@domain.com','2024-01-27 15:01:01')
,(2,0,'123.123.123.1','Ian.Wally@domain.com','2024-01-27 15:02:02')
,(3,0,'123.123.123.1','Eve.Lotion@domain.com','2024-01-27 15:03:03')
,(4,0,'123.123.123.1','Tom.hardware@domain.com','2024-01-27 15:04:04')
,(5,0,'190.190.190.2','Meg.Meghan@domain.com','2024-01-27 15:05:05')
,(6,0,'190.190.190.2','New.Meghan@domain.com','2024-01-27 15:06:05')
,(7,0,'190.190.190.2','Meg.Meghan@domain.com','2024-01-27 15:07:05')
,(8,0,'190.190.190.3','New.User@domain.com','2024-01-27 15:16:05')
,(9,0,'190.190.190.3','New.User@domain.com','2024-01-27 15:17:05')
;
select * from MySQLTableWithActivityRecords;
```

Your query output is:

| UserIP | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 123.123.123.1 | 4 |
| 190.190.190.2 | 3 |
| 190.190.190.3 | 2 |

With DISTINCT we get  result

| UserIP | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 123.123.123.1 | 4 |
| 190.190.190.2 | 2 |

For query

```
select * 
from(
 select *
  ,max(rnk)over(partition by UserIp,Format(ActivityDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH'))maxRnk
  from(
    select *
      ,rank()over(partition by UserIp,Format(ActivityDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') 
                  order by UserName) rnk
    from MySQLTableWithActivityRecords
  ) q1
)q2
where maxRnk>1
```

result is

| id | Event | UserIP | UserName | ActivityDate | rnk | maxRnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 123.123.123.1 | John.smith@domain.com | 2024-01-27 15:01:01.000 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 0 | 123.123.123.1 | Ian.Wally@domain.com | 2024-01-27 15:02:02.000 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 0 | 123.123.123.1 | Eve.Lotion@domain.com | 2024-01-27 15:03:03.000 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 0 | 123.123.123.1 | Tom.hardware@domain.com | 2024-01-27 15:04:04.000 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 0 | 190.190.190.2 | Meg.Meghan@domain.com | 2024-01-27 15:05:05.000 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 | 190.190.190.2 | New.Meghan@domain.com | 2024-01-27 15:06:05.000 | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | 0 | 190.190.190.2 | Meg.Meghan@domain.com | 2024-01-27 15:07:05.000 | 1 | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7rV84sg5)

Comment: Thanks, yes this does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself, where the JOIN condition is IP and time range:

```
SELECT L1.UserName, L2.UserName, L1.UserIP, L1.ActivityDate, L2.ActivityDate
FROM MySQLTableWithActivitiyRecords L1 -- log 1
INNER JOIN MySQLTableWithActivitiyRecords L2 -- log 2
    ON L1.UserIP = L2.UserIP AND L1.UserName <> L2.UserName 
        AND ABS(DATEDIFF(minute, L1.ActivityDate, L2.ActivityDate)) < 60
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample,  it does find the 4 records but the presentation list is a bit repeated.   I have now a working solution so case is closed